# Does $ \mathbb{E}\Big(\min_{1\leq j\leq J} |\epsilon_j|\Big)=\infty $ imply heavy tails?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expected-value

Consider $J$ continuous random variables
$$
\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_J
$$

Suppose
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big(\min_{1\leq j\leq J} |\epsilon_j|\Big)=\infty
$$

Could you help me to "graphically" interpret this condition? In particular, does it mean that there is an issue of heavy tails? If not, is there any other intuitive interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(x_1,...,x_J) \mapsto \min_{1 \le j \le J} x_j$ is concave on $\mathbb{R}^J$, Jensen's inequality gives $$\min_{1 \le j \le J} \mathbb{E}[|\epsilon_j|] \ge \mathbb{E}\left[ \min_{1 \le j \le J} |\epsilon_j|\right] = \infty,$$ so $\mathbb{E}[|\epsilon_j|] = \infty$ for all $1 \le j \le J$.  Therefore, the condition $\mathbb{E}\left[ \min_{1 \le j \le J} |\epsilon_j|\right] = \infty$ says that none of the random variables $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_J$ are integrable.  You can interpret that as saying that all of those random variables have heavy tails.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to look at it. I'll assume that the $\epsilon_j$ are iid and let $M = \min_{j\leq J} |\epsilon_j|$. I'll show by contrapositive that the $|\epsilon_j|$ being light tailed means $M$ has a finite mean.

Suppose that the $|\epsilon_j|$ are not heavy tailed, which I'll take to mean that the moment generating function (MGF) $M_{\epsilon}(t) < \infty$ for some $t$ in a neighborhood of zero.

The MGF being finite near zero means that for $t$ sufficiently small we have
$$
\text E[e^{t|\epsilon|}] = \int_0^\infty P(e^{t|\epsilon|} > x)\,\text dx = \int_0^\infty P\left(|\epsilon| > \frac{\log x}t\right)\,\text dx < \infty
$$
so it must be that $P\left(|\epsilon| > \frac{\log x}t\right) \to 0$ as a rate faster than $1/x$ as $x\to\infty$. This means $P(|\epsilon| > x)$ decays at an exponential rate at least. We then have
$$
\int_0^\infty P(M > x)\,\text dx = \int_0^\infty P(|\epsilon|> x)^J\,\text dx 
$$
and the exponential decay of $P(|\epsilon| > x)$ guarantees that this is finite, so $\text E[M] = \int_0^\infty P(M > x) < \infty$.